# How to test a specific method in a controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have a spec in my controller called `clone` in which I take a user and clone the duplicate the user.

What I need to do is within my controller (my model is `player` and so controller is `player_controller.rb`, I need to test a specific method listed below.

```
def clone
  new_player = @player.dup
  new_player.id = nil
  new_player.serial = nil
  new_player.name = "Copy of #{@player[:name]}"
end

describe '#clone' do
  it 'creates a clone of an existing player' do
    new_player = player.dup
  end
end
```

Sure what I have done in my spec is mirror the first line in the method within the controller, and so it creates a new player for me, but it doesn't update the additional features of the spec such as the name. And that is what I am having trouble. How can I specifically call out a method within my controller?

I've tried

```
new_player = player.controller.send(:clone)
```

as well as

```
new_player = player.(:clone)
```

The first error does not recognize `clone` and the second error states that I am getting an undefined method "call" for player. (I don't quite understand that error)

Would anybody know how to pull that guy out so I can test it?

Much appreciated.

Comment: That method does not belong in a controller. Controllers are orchestrators. They coordinate multiple moving pieces, but they hardly do any work themselves ("fat model, skinny controller" school of thought). If you follow that, there won't be any code in your controllers that is worth testing and is not tested already by rails or another gem. So yes, extract that cloning logic into a ServiceObject (or something), which will be trivial to test.

Answer (score 1):

In the end your controller is nothing but a Ruby class. Create an instance of it and call the method clone for the object you just created.

```
PlayerController.new.clone
```

or

```
PlayerController.new.send(:clone)
```

The issue I see here is, from where is the @player getting initialised? There will be no constructor for this class(as it is a controller). If there is some other method say 'my_test_method', that initialises it. Then call that method first on the PlayerController object and then call the clone method on the same object.

```
my_object = PlayerController.new
my_object.my_test_method
my_object.clone
```

If the clone method is getting called from an action where @player is set. Then include the specs for this method as part of the specs you are writing for that action.